# How to FORMAT MAP Data Type in vscode , Dart Programming

Tags: dart, mobile, types, format, line-breaks

The Default formating for Map data type in dart programming in vscode is :

const person = {'age': 20, 'name': 'abc'};

I want to make it like as below, when I save (ctrl+s) auto format the code as:

const person = {

```
'age': 20, 
'name': 'abc'
```

};

Comment: solution found!!! just add a comma ',' and format, that's it

const person = {

'age': 20, 
'name': 'abc',
};